# Not same build page when i did "next export" and Local Hosting(even use Vercel)

Tags: reactjs, next.js

My project is Next.JS clone Ploject.
But, My Hosting Service not support Next.JS. (I did't know before)
so, you can see on my demo page(under image) what is defferent.

First, left top side profile image is not showing.
[Static HTML Hosting page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3E1wC.png)
[Local Hosting Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2jIH.png)

Second, i can't see "my expertise", "Previous Company" in Static HTML Hosting Page.

You can see my Static hosting page in "~~~".
and full code in "~~~"

I used this module when i export Static HTML.

```
  // output: "export",
  // images: {
  //   loader: "custom",
  //   imageSizes: [16, 32, 48, 64, 96, 128, 256, 384],
  //   deviceSizes: [640, 750, 828, 1080, 1200, 1920, 2048, 3840],
  // },
  // transpilePackages: ["next-image-export-optimizer"],
  // env: {
  //   nextImageExportOptimizer_imageFolderPath: "public/images",
  //   nextImageExportOptimizer_exportFolderPath: "out",
  //   nextImageExportOptimizer_quality: "75",
  //   nextImageExportOptimizer_storePicturesInWEBP: "true",
  //   nextImageExportOptimizer_exportFolderName: "nextImageExportOptimizer",

  //   // If you do not want to use blurry placeholder images, then you can set
  //   // nextImageExportOptimizer_generateAndUseBlurImages to false and pass
  //   // `placeholder="empty"` to all <ExportedImage> components.
  //   nextImageExportOptimizer_generateAndUseBlurImages: "true",

  //   // If you want to cache the remote images, you can set the time to live of the cache in seconds.
  //   // The default value is 0 seconds.
  //   nextImageExportOptimizer_remoteImageCacheTTL: "0",
  // },
```

Looks like import something problem. but i'm not sure......

emoji.png is woking fine when i host Static HTML page.
So, i tried input the emoji.png in left top side for profile picture.
but, still not working.
that's why i thougt issue is not from picture.
even i'm tried change the file name and PNG, JPG.
but Still not working.

Comment: I finally found solution.
That issue from image path.